# SharedPreferences File Naming

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

On the `SharedPreferences` tutorial here Google says:

> When naming your shared preference files, you should use a name that's uniquely identifiable to your app. An easy way to do this is prefix the file name with your application ID. For example: "com.example.myapp.PREFERENCE_FILE_KEY"

And then Google uses `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` on its example.

**Why do we need to use our App ID if we will be using `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` anyways?**

Comment: It's either to encourage better coding practices or an oversight. Either way, most people should probably just use `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()`.

Comment: `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()` is one thing I don't get clearly from the docs...does it retrieve a private `SharedPreferences` or does it save the preferences to a more public one that a `Preferences` settings page could edit further?

Comment: I don't want to save App configurations, just to set some flags,like "run once", or "user has been warned", and thus I don't want this to be editable by any Settings page.

Comment: The default shared preference file is your package name with a `-prefs` suffix. It uses private mode. I don't believe any preference files are editable by anything but your app and any other apps with the same UID (shared UIDs). The private and public flags aren't exclusive to preferences.

Comment: good to know, thanks!